# Emacs deferred errors

Tags: python, emacs

I have installed  the Emacs package `jedi-emacs` using `M-x package install`

and the following Python packages:

- `Jedi`
- `EPC`
- `argparse`

using:

- `pip install --install-option="--prefix=~/.my_python_packages/" jedi`
- `pip install --install-option="--prefix=/.my_python_packages/" epc`
- `pip install --install-option="--prefix=/.my_python_packages/" argparse`

since I do not have root priviledges.

When I open a Python file, I get the following error in the minibuffer, no matter where I place the cursor:

`deferred error : (error Server may raise an error : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/avazquez/.emacs.d/elpa/jedi-20130119.830/jediepcserver.py", line 261, in <module>
)`

What could be causing it?

This is with `Emacs 24.2.1`

Comment: This looks like something that would warrant a bug report: https://github.com/tkf/emacs-jedi/issues

Comment: Why don't you use `pip install --user`?  Packages installed with this command are automatically added to the Python path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. I did not have `PYTHONPATH` set up correctly (it should include the corresponding paths for `/path/to/custom-packages`).

For more info on this issue see the corresponding ticket in the [package repository for emacs-jedi](https://github.com/tkf/emacs-jedi/issues/22).

Comment: I have this same issue---can I ask what you did with your python-path?