# Jedi/rope/emacs configuration for python development

Tags: python, emacs, pylint, rope, pyflakes

I think I'm having the same problem as [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14447948/emacs-deferred-errors) in getting Jedi.el to work, but more trouble with the solution.

I've installed

- EPC
- Rope
- ropemacs
- pymacs
- python-mode.el-6.1.3
- pylint
- pyflakes

I installed these things in a pretty vanilla way, using only

1. apt-get pymacs python-ropemacs pychecker pylint pyflakes ecb
2. pip install jedi
3. M-x list-packages ;; then installed auto-complete.el

That is, I included no special flags, so I expect everything is installed in the default directories.

However, I'm still getting this error:
[image]

(I would have just copied and pasted to make it searchable, but when I try to move to the buffer, it disappears!---because the buffer is sensitive the the cursor location.)

According to the stackoverflow I linked to, setting PYTHONPATH correctly should solve my problem.  But how?  Should my PYTHONPATH be `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`?  The variable is currently empty.  What is causing this set of errors that is keeping me from getting the correct tooltips popping up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, the answer was `pip install epc`.  Apparently the apt-get install was not what I needed.